# How to re-use/pass ureq agent to my threads

Tags: rust

Please consider this rust code,

```
use scoped_threadpool::Pool;
use std::thread;

const BASE_URL: &str = "https://www.bing.com/search?q=";

struct my_struct<'a> {
    url: &'a str,
    id: i16,
}

impl my_struct<'_> {
    fn doGet(&self) -> bool {
        let resp = ureq::get(self.url).timeout_connect(5_000).call();
        if !resp.ok() {
            return false;
        } else {
            return resp.ok();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let our_vec = (1..11).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let mut pool = Pool::new(3);

    pool.scoped(|scoped| {
        for entry in our_vec {
            scoped.execute(move || {
                let url = format!("{}{}", BASE_URL, entry);
                let this_item = my_struct {
                    url: &url,
                    id: entry,
                };
                let our_bool = this_item.doGet();
                println!("{} status: {}", entry, our_bool);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

It generates 10 urls, and do a minimal `GET` on each, and it works. However, the above code uses new connection for each url, and is thus too costly for my real situation.  `ureq` seems to have [Agent](https://docs.rs/ureq/0.8.2/ureq/struct.Agent.html) that supports connection pooling.

So I tried:

```
const BASE_URL: &str = "https://www.bing.com/search?q=";
use scoped_threadpool::Pool;
use std::thread;

struct my_struct<'a> {
    url: &'a str,
    id: i16,
}

impl my_struct<'_> {
    fn doGet(&self) -> bool {
        let resp = ureq::get(self.url).timeout_connect(5_000).call();
        if !resp.ok() {
            return false;
        } else {
            return resp.ok();
        }
    }
    fn doGet_withAgent(&self, some_Agent: &ureq::Agent) -> bool {
        return true;
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let our_vec = (1..11).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let mut pool = Pool::new(3);
    let agent = ureq::Agent::new();

    pool.scoped(|scoped| {
        for entry in our_vec {
            scoped.execute(move || {
                let url = format!("{}{}", BASE_URL, 3);
                let this_item = my_struct {
                    url: &url,
                    id: entry,
                };
                //let our_bool = this_item.doGet();
                let our_bool = this_item.doGet_withAgent(&agent);
                println!("{} status: {}", entry, our_bool);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

but cannot seem to get it correct:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `agent`
  --> src/main.rs:33:28
   |
33 |             scoped.execute(move || {
   |                            ^^^^^^^ value moved into closure here, in previous iteration of loop
...
40 |                 let our_bool = this_item.doGet_withAgent(&agent);
   |                                                           ----- use occurs due to use in closure
```

My objective is to reuse my connections. What's the idiomatic way to achieve this?

**Edit 1**

```
const BASE_URL: &str = "https://www.bing.com/search?q=";
use scoped_threadpool::Pool;
use std::thread;

struct my_struct<'a> {
    url: &'a str,
    id: i16,
}

impl my_struct<'_> {
    fn doGet(&self) -> bool {
        let resp = ureq::get(self.url).timeout_connect(5_000).call();
        if !resp.ok() {
            return false;
        } else {
            return resp.ok();
        }
    }
    fn doGet_withAgent(&self, some_Agent: &ureq::Agent) -> bool {
        let resp = some_Agent.get(self.url).timeout_connect(5_000).call();
        return true;
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let our_vec = (1..11).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let mut pool = Pool::new(3);
    let mut agent = ureq::Agent::new();

    pool.scoped(|scoped| {
        for entry in our_vec {
            let agent = &agent;
            scoped.execute(move || {
                let url = format!("{}{}", BASE_URL, entry);
                let this_item = my_struct {
                    url: &url,
                    id: entry,
                };
                let our_bool = this_item.doGet_withAgent(agent);
                println!("{} status: {}", entry, our_bool);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit 2**

So I wrapped the agent in an `ARC`, still using new connections for consecutive requests.

```
const BASE_URL: &str = "https://www.google.com/search?q=";
use scoped_threadpool::Pool;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::thread;

struct my_struct<'a> {
    url: &'a str,
    id: i16,
}

impl my_struct<'_> {
    fn doGet(&self) -> bool {
        let resp = ureq::get(self.url).timeout_connect(5_000).call();
        return resp.ok();
    }

    //fn doGet_withAgent(&self, some_Agent: ureq::Agent) -> bool {
    //fn doGet_withAgent(&self, some_mutex: &std::sync::Arc)-> bool{
    fn doGet_withAgent(&self, some_mutex: Arc<Mutex<ureq::Agent>>) -> bool {
        let mut guard = some_mutex.lock().unwrap();
        let resp = guard.head(self.url).timeout_connect(5_000).call();
        return resp.ok();
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let our_vec = (1..11).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let mut pool = Pool::new(3);
    let agent = Arc::new(Mutex::new(ureq::Agent::new()));

    pool.scoped(|scoped| {
        for entry in our_vec {
            let agent_clone = agent.clone();
            scoped.execute(move || {
                let url = format!("{}{}", BASE_URL, 3);
                let this_item = my_struct {
                    url: &url,
                    id: entry,
                };
                let our_bool = this_item.doGet_withAgent(agent_clone);
                println!("{} status: {}", entry, our_bool);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't know much about the `ureq` crate, but from a quick scan of their documentation it looks like the `Agent` type implements `Clone`. Maybe try having a separate clone of `Agent` for each closure instance in the loop. Specifically, try putting the line - `let agent = agent.clone();` - just above where you call `scoped.execute`.

In other words, the compiler is telling you that the `agent` variable gets _moved_ into the closure during the first iteration of the `for` loop (because of the `move` keyword on the nested closure). So it is no longer available for subsequent iterations.

Comment: thanks, tired that - it still spawns new connections for each attempt. until we use the same `agent` object for all the iterations that seems to be  the case.

Comment: Ah. How about if you put this line - `let agent = &agent;` - above the line where you call `scoped.execute`? And you can also remove the `&` on the `agent` variable when you call `doGet_withAgent`.

Comment: see Edit 1 above, still spawns new connections - likely since `let agent = &agent;` is immutable - the thread won't write its goodies into agent's struct stuff since it just cannot..

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching to `reqwest` from `ureq`

**Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
scoped_threadpool = "0.1.9"
reqwest = { version = "0.10", features = ["blocking"] }
...
```

```
const BASE_URL: &str = "https://www.BinG.com/search?q=";
use scoped_threadpool::Pool;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::thread;

struct my_struct<'a> {
    url: &'a str,
    id: i16,
}

impl my_struct<'_> {
    fn doGet_withAgent(&self, some_mutex: Arc<Mutex<reqwest::blocking::Client>>) -> bool {
        let resp;
        let mut guard = some_mutex.lock().unwrap();
        match guard.head(self.url).send() {
            Ok(in_here) => {
                resp = in_here;
            }
            _ => {
                return false;
            }
        }

        match resp.status().as_u16() {
            200 => {
                return true;
            }
            _ => (),
        }

        return false;
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let our_vec = (1..11).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let mut pool = Pool::new(2);

    let agent = Arc::new(Mutex::new(reqwest::blocking::Client::new()));
    pool.scoped(|scoped| {
        for entry in our_vec {
            let agent_clone = agent.clone();
            scoped.execute(move || {
                let url = format!("{}{}", BASE_URL, entry);
                let this_item = my_struct {
                    url: &url,
                    id: entry,
                };

                let our_bool = this_item.doGet_withAgent(agent_clone);
                println!("{} status: {}", entry, our_bool);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

It behaves well with respect to connection re-using, although I am not certain threading is of much help:

```
Hello, world!
1 status: true
2 status: true
3 status: true
4 status: true
5 status: true
6 status: true
7 status: true
8 status: true
9 status: true
10 status: true
```

The execution seems sequential, not sure if I'd see a difference if I switch to `async` instead of `blocking` `reqwest`.

Comment: Note that if you want all the requests to use the same connection, then they will necessarily be sequential since a connection can only service one request at a time.

Comment: thanks, unlike golang where http clients are [safe](https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go) for concurrent use by multiple goroutines - I learned not every rust implementation may not be thread capable. I then found [isahc](https://crates.io/crates/isahc), its HttpClient is entirely thread-safe. will update my answer above to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

unlike golang where http clients are [safe](https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go) for concurrent use by multiple goroutines - I have learned every rust implementation may not be thread capable/safe.

Then found [isahc](https://crates.io/crates/isahc), its [HttpClient](https://docs.rs/isahc/0.6.0/isahc/struct.HttpClient.html) is entirely thread-safe. much simpler, no `ARC` mutex stuff needed, as it can work on a muted reference to `client`:

**Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
scoped_threadpool = "0.1.9"
isahc = "0.8.2"
```

**Code:**

```
const BASE_URL: &str = "https://www.BinG.com/search?q=";
use scoped_threadpool::Pool;
use isahc::prelude::*;

struct my_struct<'a> {
    url: &'a str,
    id: i16,
}

impl my_struct<'_> {
    fn doGet_withClient(&self, incoming_client: &isahc::HttpClient) -> bool {
        let response;
        match incoming_client.get(self.url) {
            Ok(resp) => {
                response = resp;
            }
            _ => {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return response.status().is_success();

        return false;
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let our_vec = (1..11).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let mut pool = Pool::new(4);
    let client;
    match HttpClient::new() {
        Ok(this_thing) => {
            client = this_thing;
        }
        _ => {
            panic!("could not get http client thingy");
        }
    }

    pool.scoped(|scoped| {
        for entry in our_vec {
            let new_client = &client;
            scoped.execute(move || {
                let url = format!("{}{}", BASE_URL, entry);
                let this_item = my_struct {
                    url: &url,
                    id: entry,
                };

                let our_bool = this_item.doGet_withClient(new_client);
                println!("{} status: {}", entry, our_bool);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Running it:

```
Hello, world!
3 status: true
4 status: true
2 status: true
1 status: true
5 status: true
6 status: true
8 status: true
9 status: true
10 status: true
7 status: true
```